# asp.net DetailsVeiw - insert a item in a dropdownlist when Insert LinkButton Selected

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET. I am trying to insert a item into a dropdownlist when click "New" to add new record.  which the form will switch from ItemTemplate to InsertTempplate

Error:

> "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object."

this code in my DetailsView.

```
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblVendorName" 
        runat="Server" style="text-align:left; width:100%" 
        Text='<%# Eval("VendorName")%>' Width="70%"/>

    </ItemTemplate>    
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList id="insertVendorName" datasourceid="VendorSqlDataSource"
            datatextfield="VendorName" DataValueField="VendorID"  
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlVendor_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="VendorSqlDataSource"  
        ConnectionString="<%$Connectionstrings:ConnectionString%>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT VendorID, VendorName 
                from MDF_Vendor"  runat="server">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
```

Updated... Below is set of Link Bottons.

```
<asp:TemplateField>  
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnedit" runat="server" 
            CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"/>  |   
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnInsert" runat="Server" 
            Text="New" CommandName="New" 
            OnClick="LinkButton_Click"  />  |  
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" 
            runat="server" 
            CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />      | 
    </ItemTemplate>  

    <InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnInsert" runat="Server" 
        Text="Insert" CommandName="Insert"/>    
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btncancel" runat="server" 
        CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"/> 
    </InsertItemTemplate>

    <EditItemTemplate>                                                 
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnupdate" runat="server" 
            CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />                  
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btncancel" runat="server" 
            CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"/>       
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I tried this code below suggested by @Aghislas (Thanks!)

```
protected void LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlVendor = (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("insertVendorName"); 
    ddlVendor.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "-1"));
}
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What are you tying to do achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this code

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" 
       Text="Click Me" 
       OnClick="LinkButton_Click" 
       runat="server"/>


 protected void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
      var ddlVendor =(DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("insertVendorName");

      ddlVendor.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "-1"));
 }
```

Nota : You delete code in the `Page_Load` and move in Click delegate

Comment: I am gettting this error when I tried your code "CS0122: '_Default.LinkButton_Click(object, System.EventArgs)' is inaccessible due to its protection level".  Please advise!

Comment: @Milacay i added protected , link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.click.aspx

Comment: Thanks alot for being really helpful.  Sorry, I am still getting "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." looks like dllVendor is not being created as an object?

Comment: I figured it out now.  Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help you Milacay Thank's